# Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: spring, sql, spring-boot, jpa

Creé una interface *IUSuarioRepository* aquí se encuentra la query:

```
package com.eventos.backendeventos.repository;

import com.eventos.backendeventos.models.entity.Usuario;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface IUsuarioRepository extends CrudRepository<Usuario, String>{
    
    public Usuario findByUsuario(String IDUSUARIO_RED);
    
    @Query("select u from Usuario u where u.IDUSUARIO_RED=09356")
    public Usuario findByUsuario2(String IDUSUARIO_RED);
}
```

Y esta es mi entidad Usuario no se si el error este relacionado con que la id es string:

```
package com.eventos.backendeventos.models.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="USUARIO_EVENTO")
public class Usuario implements Serializable{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String IDUSUARIO_RED;
    
    @Column(length = 60)
    private String contrasenia;
    
    private Boolean enabled;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="USUARIO_EVENTO_ROLES", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "IDUSUARIO_RED"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idrol"))
    private List<Rol> roles;

    public String getIDUSUARIO_RED() {
        return IDUSUARIO_RED;
    }

    public void setIDUSUARIO_RED(String IDUSUARIO_RED) {
        this.IDUSUARIO_RED = IDUSUARIO_RED;
    }

    public String getContrasenia() {
        return contrasenia;
    }

    public void setContrasenia(String contrasenia) {
        this.contrasenia = contrasenia;
    }

    public Boolean getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(Boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public List<Rol> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Rol> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

Este es el error, al parecer es algo del query:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.eventos.backendeventos.models.entity.Usuario com.eventos.backendeventos.repository.IUsuarioRepository.findByUsuario(java.lang.String)! No property usuario found for type Usuario!

Comment: Cuando extiendes los repositorios de JPA debes tener en cuenta una cosa muy importante, el nombre de los métodos define la implementación de los mismos! Si tu método se llama `findByUsuario`, no puedes pasarle un string de un campo que no existe... es decir, ese método está intentando buscar una variable de tu clase que se llame Usuario y sea un string, cosa que no existe. El método debería llamarse `findByIDUSUARIO_RED`, lo cual por cierto no respeta la nomenclatura camelCase...

Comment: gracias le cambie el nombre y me compilo todo ok